# Merge from VisualStudio Online to local TFS and back?

Tags: tfs, version-control, azure-devops, tfvc

Have an in house TFS server that employees use (using TFVC) and third-party contractors that are using VisualStudio Team Services (aka Visual Studio Online or VSO) (also using TFVC). Need to keep the two synced; projects in VSO get merges from check-ins from TFS and TFS get merges from VSO. The TFS instance has many dozen projects and the VSO instance has two or three of those in TFS.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

While there are a few tools that can "sync" between different TFVC instances, it's very hard to keep the flow going and you often run into merge conflicts and other problems. The TFS Integration tools were an official solution from Microsoft, but those have been deprecated.

Given that you're on TFS 2017 and VSTS, I'd highly recommend switching to Git repositories. Git was made to handle scenarios like these, to have multiple hosts that need to share the history and from which you need to be able to sync sources across.

Both TFS 2017 and VSTS can host the repository for you and it's relatively easy to setup CI builds that sync the sources between branches on both instances to trigger pull requests.